# Info on Informix Database 3.5

Tags: database, informix

When was Informix Database 3.5 released? And what is the "End of Life" of this version?

Comment: AFAIK, there was never an Informix database with version number 3.50, dating back to the 80s. There was ClientSDK 3.50 associated with Informix Dynamic Server 11.50.  That reached its end of life a few years ago, superseded by server versions 11.70, 12.10, and 14.10, accompanied by ClientSDK versions 3.70, 4.10, 4.50.  Versions 11.70 and 3.70 reach their end of life later this year.  Can you clarify what you're referring to?

Comment: The nearest approach to 3.50 was the pre-SQL Informix 3.30, last released circa 1986. The SQL versions went from a mix of 1.x and 2.x versions to 4.00 circa 1990, precisely to avoid confusion with the then still recent Informix 3.x versions.  We can discuss the versioning of CSDK at length another time, but it is mostly sour grapes on my part and water under the bridge; what happened can't be changed now.

Comment: Dear Jonathan, you are right the version 3.50 is related to the SDK. Thanks about your feedback and your clarification. Best regards MJ

Comment: Dear Jonathan, thanks about your feedback. Best regards